# Center buttons with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make buttons go across the page in the center and when it runs out of room on the right it would go the next layer and add more buttons. I have 4 buttons but they get stuck the left side [picture of the buttons on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE7f8.png)

[image]

Here is the code on the CSS/HTML side.

```css
#cyber-courses-bottom button
 {
   display:block; /* change this from inline-block */
   height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
     margin:0 auto; /* this will center  it */
   float:left;
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   position:relative;
     font-style:normal;
     font-weight:normal;
     color:#fff;
     border:none;
   border-radius: 0;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-align:center;
     cursor:pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     background-color:#820024;
}

.clearFloat {clear: both;}
.floatRight {float: right;}

#cyber-courses-bottom button:hover,
#cyber-courses-bottom button:focus
{
  background: #fff;
  color: #820024;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
        <div id="cyber-courses-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                      <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources</button>
           <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources2</button>
           <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources3</button>
           <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources4</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What it should look like? I mean the output you want.

Comment: @John Rey M. Baylen I want it to look something like this (http://i.imgur.com/xMbxObd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpGmBW

```css
#cyber-courses-bottom button
 {
   display:block; /* change this from inline-block */
   height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   position:relative;
     font-style:normal;
     font-weight:normal;
     color:#fff;
     border:none;
   border-radius: 0;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-align:center;
     cursor:pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     background-color:#820024;
}
.col-md-6 {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#cyber-courses-bottom button:hover,
#cyber-courses-bottom button:focus
{
  background: #fff;
  color: #820024;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
        <div id="cyber-courses-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                      <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources</button>
           <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources2</button>
           <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources3</button>
           <button align="right" class="smoothScroll btn btn-default wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000" >Resources4</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it still aligns all to the left. I'm wondering if it has to do with something on the other layouts on other classes like floats. [This is what the page looks like](http://i.imgur.com/Z0dDt1Z.png)

Comment: You should have included all related code. It's most likely nested in another element which is floated left. If you include all related code, then we can see if we can make that thing centered :D

Comment: This is the code of the main course body before the buttons. here is the picture (https://gyazo.com/9a5b0b1530f9f955d60d061083c134a7) @Mers

Comment: You have to provide your HTML structure too. We need to see how your two paragraphs above the buttons are structured. But here, check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpGmBW. However, if you want someone to assist you, you need to show all relevant code (HTML and CSS). As it stands now, all answers provided to your original question are valid as they resolve what you asked - initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily with Flexbox

```
.centered-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

See this Codepen: http://codepen.io/oculusriff/pen/Qprvmo

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
.fadeInLeft {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what others have said, use FlexBox.

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

would center your buttons and as you shrink the page the buttons will pop down to a new line and create two rows.  Here is a quick overview of Flexbox : https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_flexbox.asp